# Android FirebaseDatabase after Data Change, values are shown twice

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

always if a change in my db happened, the old values and the new ones are shown. How can i delete the old ones and show only the new one. Here is my code:

```
 private void downloadAccepted(final String plz) {
    String userid = 
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid).child("acceptedEvents");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                downloadAcceptedDetails(plz, snapshot.getKey().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
private void downloadAcceptedDetails(final String plz, final String id){

    DatabaseReference refi = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child(plz).child(id);
    refi.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Long millis =  new Date().getTime();
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0 ) {
                if (Long.parseLong(dataSnapshot.child("ts").getValue().toString()) > millis) {
                    EventObject eo = new EventObject(dataSnapshot.child("ts").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("street").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("plz").getValue().toString());
                    accepted.add(eo);
                    try{
                        ((globalVariable) getActivity().getApplication()).setAdapter2(adapter2);
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    removeValuesMyIdeas( plz, id);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

and the onData Change in my downloadAccepted is always called. i already tried to do the following in the method before:

```
accepted = new ArrayList();
```

Unfortunately if i add this line to one of both methods, nothing is shown always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the old data using `accepted.clear()` before start processing the response

```
   ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            accepted.clear();
            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                downloadAcceptedDetails(plz, snapshot.getKey().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

[Pavneet's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52709726) works, but means you refresh the entire list whenever there's a change in any child. If you want more granular updates, you'll want to use a `ChildEventListener`, which tells you which child nodes were added, removed, modified or moved.

A simple example for the first listener you shared:

```
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        downloadAcceptedDetails(plz, dataSnapshot.getKey().toString());
    }
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // TODO: remove `dataSnapshot.getKey()` from the list
    }
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        // TODO: update `dataSnapshot.getKey()` in the list
    }
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        // TODO: move `dataSnapshot.getKey()` in the list
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore exceptions
    }
});
```

Also see [working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events).